# Attribute Error when i try to test my chatbot 3 endpoints = 'endpoints.y

Tags: rasa-nlu

from rasa.jupyter import chat

endpoints = 'endpoints.yml'

chat(model_path, endpoints)

i was trying to test the chatbot so that i can further modify it according to my requirements

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 5>()
3 endpoints = 'endpoints.yml'
4
----> 5 chat(model_path, endpoints)

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rasa/core/agent.py in load_agent(model_path, model_server, remote_storage, endpoints, loop)
222
223     if endpoints:
--> 224         broker = await EventBroker.create(endpoints.event_broker, loop=loop)
225         tracker_store = TrackerStore.create(
226             endpoints.tracker_store, event_broker=broker

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'event_broker'